# Ambigous reference when using the CodeBehind pattern

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, mxml, code-behind

I'm getting the ambiguous reference error when trying to bind properties. Here's the code:

MXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<custom:Test
    xmlns:mx        = "library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    xmlns:fx        = "http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:custom    = "CodeBehind.*">

    <mx:TextInput id = "foo" text = "foo!">
    </mx:TextInput>

    <mx:TextInput id = "bar" text = "{foo}">
    </mx:TextInput>

</custom:Test>
```

CodeBehind

```
package CodeBehind
{
    import mx.containers.Panel;

    public class Test extends Panel
    {

    }
}
```

Here's the error itself:

```
/Front/Test.mxml(-1):  Error: Ambiguous reference to Test.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Strangely enough, it doesn't even mention the binded property...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I've managed to solve it. I renamed Front/Test.mxml to Front/TestDisplay.mxml and that did the trick - no more ambiguous reference.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce the error. Everything compiled in FB4.
I assumed the structure was

Front
-> | Test.mxml
CodeBehind
-> | Test.as

Possible choices :

- Check your folder/package structure
- Are there any other files with `Test` as the name or auto-generated files?
- I have seen others had bad builds with their Flex Builder so try cleaning the project set.

Comment: I'm compiling from the command line with AMXMLC, not the IDE. Air 2.5 SDK to be exact. I'm also running Linux (in case that makes a difference).

And yes, the folder structure is correct - appNameRoot/CodeBehind and appNameRoot/Front to be exact.